# How do you sync changes between multiple codebases?

Tags: codebase

Let's say I want to create a spinoff of a chat application branded under a different name, different UI, and some changed features. How would one sync changes between these to codebases which are 80% the same?

EDIT: Already use git.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty generic question and one that should be covered in any basic Software Engineering course.

I'd start with:

1. SCM (Source CodeManagement) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Management
2. Separate 'shared' code into libraries (either statically or dynamically linked)

There is a whole field of experts and products on this topic - revision control and merging.

Comment: +1 very valuable suggestion.  Have a library for the common code, and have the applications have the context specific-code.

Comment: thanks! already use git. good suggestion for libraries - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a distributed code repository, if it is usually a one-way sync (main development pushes to spinoff project).

[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) is one of the most popular DCR 
There are many distributed code repository systems.  The website provide a nice [tutorial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tutorial).

Comment: Look at subversion, git, bazaar.  I hear good things about git for really distributed source management.

Comment: @Jim, SVN isn't good for this case scenario I think.  Added a reference to `hg` which is a bit easier to use than `git` for new comers IMHO.